# Can I Pass Compilation Constants to a Project Reference?

Tags: c#, msbuild

If I have a `<ProjectReference>` reference, is there any way to pass a conditional compilation value to that project? Something like this (I know `<DefineConstants>` doesn't exist like this, it's just to illustrate the need):

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\DataProducer\DataProducer.csproj">
  <DefineConstants>WAS_SET</DefineConstants>
<ProjectReference>
```

Therefore, if there's a class in that project like this:

```
    public sealed class ProduceValue
    {
        public string Produce()
        {
#if WAS_SET
            return "WAS SET";
#else
            return "NOTHING WAS SET";
#endif
        }
    }
```

Then by passing that value during compilation or not, I could get different output.

Answer (score 11):

The `ProjectReference` item allows adding the metadata fields `Properties` and `UndefineProperties` to allow maninpulating the set of "global" properties that are used to build project references. You could make use of this by passing in a global property to the referenced project like this:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\DataProducer\DataProducer.csproj">
  <Properties>DefineConstants=WAS_SET</Properties>
</ProjectReference>
```

The effect of this now being a global property to the referenced project is that it will override any definition/update of `DefineConstants` defined statically in the project - this may also include any added configuration constant (`DEBUG`).

Comment: This looks promising, but I tried your idea and it doesn't seem to change the referenced project. I've put my solution into a GitHub repo if you want to see what I did:

https://github.com/JasonBock/ChangeConditionalCompilation

I could be doing something wrong - please let me know if there's something I missed.

Comment: My gut feeling tells me that there are certainly going to be problems with incremental compilation when you build a complete solution with multiple projects doing this.. I'll have a look at it in a few hours, in the meantime I suggest trying to clean on build only one project at a time from the command line to see what happens.

Comment: I agree about the potential problems. Just curious to see if it's possible :).

Comment: @JasonBock have you found any solution for this yet?

Answer (score 1):

If constants are determined by Startup project then you can create a new configuration for your projects and add constants to those new configurations.

Then, in your DataProducer.csproj you can have something like this

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <Configurations>Debug;Release;DebugMYCONSTANTS</Configurations>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='DebugMYCONSTANTS|AnyCPU'">
  <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);WAS_SET</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

After this you just need to launch your project with DebugMYCONSTANTS configuration.

Alternatively, you can just check configuration instead of the constants

```
public sealed class ProduceValue
{
    public string Produce()
    {
#if DebugMYCONSTANTS
        return "WAS SET";
#else
        return "NOTHING WAS SET";
#endif
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue.

There were 2 projects with the same types inside (let's call them *CommonTypes1* and *CommonTypes2*).

Also, there was another project (let's name it *Models*) which had to be dependent on CommonTypes**1** or CommonTypes**2** based on some condition.
Then I wanted:

- build my App**1** with referencing to *Models* (and Models referencing to CommonTypes**1**).
- build my App**2** with referencing to *Models* (and Models referencing to CommonTypes**2**).

I tried different approaches realated to project references, properties, configurations, msbuild tasks and etc.
But solved the issue by creation addition Models**2** project, but instead of copying all cs files, I have used links like:

```
in  Models2.csproject:

<Compile 
    Include="..\Models\**\*.cs" 
    Exclude="..\Models\bin\**\*.*;..\Models\obj\**\*.*">
</Compile>
```

See more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2022)

Answer (score -1):

I think the possible soution is "Targets" of "ProjectReference"
https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/master/src/MSBuild/MSBuild/Microsoft.Build.CommonTypes.xsd#L644

define a target in DataProducer.csproj.
define the Constants property in the target.
thus make the target before build target.

then it should works?

**Update**:

tried my prev option, it doesn't works.
another option:

1. copy DataProducer.csproj and rename to DataProducer.WAS_SET.csproj
2. add DefineConstants for DataProducer.WAS_SET.csproj
3. update ProjectReference Include="..\DataProducer\DataProducer.WAS_SET.csproj"

so DataProducer.csproj & DataProducer.WAS_SET.csproj will share the code.
and we could refer to any one we want.

and we could use different AssemblyName for that two csproj.
thus same source code, but different dll.